# Azure variable is not being read correctly in build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

In my build pipeline I've defined a variable that holds a password:

> To reference a variable in YAML, prefix it with a dollar sign and enclose it in parentheses. For example: $(ACCOUNT_PASSWORD)

I have a task that uses the [file creator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eliostruyf.build-task) extension:

```
- task: file-creator@6
  inputs:
    filepath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/cypress.env.json'
    filecontent: |
      {
        "ACCOUNT_PASSWORD": $(ACCOUNT_PASSWORD)
      }
    fileoverwrite: true
```

But I get this error:

> `SyntaxError: /home/**/_work/1/s/cypress.env.json: Unexpected token $ in JSON at position 24`

So I create a json file and I think the `$(ACCOUNT_PASSWORD)` is interpreted as a regular string in stead of the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of syntax, it is expecting but you can try variables['ACCOUNT_PASSWORD']

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
- task: file-creator@6
  inputs:
    filepath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/cypress.env.json'
    filecontent: |
      {
        "ACCOUNT_PASSWORD": "ACCOUNT_PASSWORD"
      }
    fileoverwrite: true

- task: FileTransform@1
  inputs:
    folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    fileType: 'json'
    targetFiles: 'cypress.env.json'
```